# notepad++ replace space and , with ,

Tags: regex, notepad++

i am completely bad with replace option in notepad++ but i use it to edit my txt files and some of the books for my kindle in txt format.

The problem is, in some lines i've got this problem:

example

Emily was a pretty girl
, but noone realy liked her.

I would be realy greatfull is someone can help me to replace this space-newline-come to come so the text will look like this

Emily was a pretty girl, but noone realy liked her.

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to replace this regex:

```
\s+,
```

With this:

```
,
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option you could do here is use a **Negative Lookahead**.

```
Find: \s+(?![^,])
Replace:
```

Regular expression:

```
\s+            whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
 (?!           look ahead to see if there is not:
  [^,]         any character except: ','
 )             end of look-ahead
```

Or lookahead to see if there is not word characters.

```
Find: \s+(?!\w)
Replace:
```

Regular expression:

```
\s+            whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
 (?!           look ahead to see if there is not:
  \w           word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
 )             end of look-ahead
```

You could also use a Positive Lookahead here to look ahead to see if there is non-word characters.

```
Find: \s+(?=\W)
Replace:
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another ***Positive Lookahead*** as follows

```
Find    : \s+(?=,)
Replace :
```

Regular expression:

```
\s+            whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
 (?=           look ahead to see if there is :
   ,           comma
 )             end of look-ahead
```